# Issue with If and Return Statements

Tags: javascript

Where is my mistake?  I know it has something to do with where my if statements are in relation to the loop, but I can't put my finger on it. The goal is to make the function check to see if the object has a certain property, and then to return the property.

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
// Only change code below this line
 for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
     if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       return contacts[i][prop];
     }   
   } 

   else if (firstName !== contacts[i].firstName) {
     return "No such contact";
   }

   return "No such property";
 } 




// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

Comment: Problem is you're checking only for `i = 0` and immediately returning. Your failure for `No such contact` and `No such property` need to be placed in a way that allows it to check every index.

Comment: You're saying `if (x === y)` and then later `if (y !== x)` which makes no sense. The second branch is the logical inverse of the first.

Comment: Read what @PatrickRoberts wrote. One thing you could do is complete all iterations of your `for {...}` loop, and then at the end of the function, return `no such contact` if that line is reached (whereas if a match is found, you do a return from within the loop and your "no match" line would never be reached.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comments, you need to move your failure conditions such that the `for` loop is able to check the necessary indices before returning:

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }

      return "No such property";
    }
  }

  return "No such contact";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

Alternatively, you could employ a slightly more functional programming approach by using [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  const contact = contacts.find(
    contact => contact.firstName === firstName
  );
  
  if (contact === undefined) {
    return "No such contact";
  }
  
  if (contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    return contact[prop];
  }
  
  return "No such property";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

Comment: I was unaware of the `Array.find()` method +1

Comment: @Jhecht it was introduced in the ES6 specification

Comment: I'm sure it was, I've just never had a need for it so I've never needed to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `return "No such property";` should be outside of the `for`loop. Being inside the `for` loop that statement terminating the loop after first iteration.

Also you do not need `else if (...` because you are returning that from outside `for` loop.

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

 for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
   if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
     return contacts[i][prop];
   }   
  } 
 } 

 return "No such property";
}

// Change these values to test your function
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"))
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "lastName"))
```

**OR:** If you are comfortable with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  var res = contacts.filter(p => p.firstName === firstName);
  if (res.length > 0 && res[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
   return res[0][prop];
  } 

 return "No such property";
}

// Change these values to test your function
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"))
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "lastName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had gotten most of this written out before Mamun, but I'd like to talk a bit more about this answer and what you're doing

For my solution I am simply filtering the array down to only things that have the correct first name. If you are sure that your elements will have distinct first names, then this is a fine solution as you should only ever expect the length of the filtered array to be either 0 or 1. Now, the downside is that `Array.filter()` runs throughout the entire length of the array, continuing even after we've found our person. For a short array, like the example, that's not a problem. For an array with 10,000 elements and our person is the first searched, bit of a performance issue.

The other problem is: what happens if you have more than one person with the same first name? Well your filtered array will be larger than 1, but we're only ever going to be using the first result -- could be a problem.

Also, if you plan on looking information up *frequently* you may want to consider using what is known as a "hash map" -- these are fairly simple things with complicated sounding names.

What makes one entry unique from another? In most cases we have some variety of ID that comes with the data from the database, but in this case we don't have that. We must then ask ourselves what makes "Kristian Vos" different than say "Krtistian Paule"(assuming both are in the same pulled data). Using what we know to be important information about the objects (in this case, first + last name) we create a unique key to store the data in an object. That way we can look things up much faster by simply accessing the Object with our mapped keys.

My point in all of this being: Be careful to think about what you will be doing with your solution, and understand that small datasets are generally cheap to continuously transverse, but imagine for some reason your array contains 10,000 or 100,000 entries -- are you working with the data in the most reasonable way?

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
  let profile = contacts.filter(person=> person.firstName == firstName);
  //Get only the person who has the same first name
  if(!profile.length) return false;
  //If the length is 0, then !0 will be truthy and the function will immediately return false
  profile = profile[0];
  //this is pure laziness, you could just alter the next line to read profile[0][prop] but I'll be honest i did this for visual appeal
  return profile[prop] || false;
  // this notation is fucky -- if the property is set on the profile, then it will return that value.
  // if it is not set, it'll return undefined, which is a falsey value and will therefore move over to the other side of the || and return that value, which is false.
}

console.log(lookUpProfile('Kristian', 'lastName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter method and check the falsey values

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
         "lastName":"Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  let filtered=contacts.filter(c=>c.firstName==firstName);
  return filtered.map(f=>f[prop] || 'not found');
}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

If you want to return only one entry you can use `find`

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
         "lastName":"Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  let filtered=contacts.find(c=>c.firstName==firstName);
  return filtered[prop] || 'not found';
}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```